# #1005 - Can't create table 'demo.survey' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have to create Survey table with foreign key but it give error. like

## 1005 - Can't create table 'demo.survey' (errno: 150)

so what should I do..

```
CREATE TABLE Survey
(
    sno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sname TEXT NOT NULL,
    sfpname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    sdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    sfcrno INT NOT NULL,
    sfpno INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(sfpname) REFERENCES Product(pname),
    FOREIGN KEY(sfcrno) REFERENCES SurveyCreater(crno),
    FOREIGN KEY(sfpno) REFERENCES Product(pno),
    PRIMARY KEY(sno)
);

CREATE TABLE SurveyCreater
(
    crno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    crname TEXT NOT NULL,
    dob DATE NOT NULL,
    gender TEXT NOT NULL,
    address TEXT,
    city TEXT,
    state TEXT,
    contact TEXT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(crno)               
);
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    pno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    pdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    pfcrno INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(pfcrno) REFERENCES SurveyCreater(crno),
    PRIMARY KEY(pno) 
);
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY(sfpno) REFERENCES Product(pno)`, a foreign key can only reference a primary or unique key,i added a unique key on pno,and order of tables doesnt matter if you set foreign key checks=o so you dont have to move the tables See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef3b4

Comment: I tried according to your solution. It work. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables have foreign keys integrated which reference each other. So, the order of creation matters, becasue you can only reference another table/column if it exists.

Regarding the SQL code you provided create the tables in the following order:

1. SurveyCreater (has no foreign keys)
2. Product (references only SurveyCreater)
3. Surveys (references SurveyCreater and Product)

Answer (score 0):

You have given reference to foreign key column which does not exist that is why mySQl error 150 is coming Try executing your create query in following order.

- SurveyCreator
- Product
- Survey